# Adobe Reader install

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, adobe, reader

im kinda stuck with installation of Adobe reader trough intune powershell or even cmd.

My goal is to install Adobe Reader trough intune (msi) or trough intune scripting.

i got scripts working and my target pc is local admin but i want a quiet install with no addition popups.

I have tried multiple tutorials and scripts but no success so far. the .msi that adobe proved cant be installed trough intune because i get a error after the instalation. (no logging file or something to figure out what is going wrong, So fine i make a script dat copy's all the files and tried to run the setup.exe or to AcroRead.msi but i dont silent install. through cmd i got it working with

```
setup.exe /sall /l*v "target logging"
```

when i run that without cmd or powershell it works only with a UAC prompt before it.My guess is that the script wont work because of the UAC in the beginning? (i get no error's in powershell)

my current powershell script is :

```
########## Set Execution Policy, to be able to run scripts ##########
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
########## make C:\temp ##########
mkdir C:\temp
########## Set the PowerShell Variables ##########
$source = "ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK ETkCWvOktxFGs4KRCE8pf_4B4sTsz3EkafcI6XhDIR6nAA?e=sxBms3&download=1"
$destination = "c:\temp\abcpy.ini"
########## Download the Executable ##########
Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination

$source1 = "ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK r2sE6zDU3396IBi4pw?e=HbmOkl&download=1"
$destination1 = "c:\temp\AcroRdrDCUpd1900820071.msp"
########## Download the Executable ##########
Invoke-WebRequest $source1 -OutFile $destination1

$source2 = "ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK zTiO1WJYqbCeog?e=bqUHey&download=1"
$destination2 = "c:\temp\AcroRead.msi"
########## Download the Executable ##########
Invoke-WebRequest $source2 -OutFile $destination2

$source3 = "ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK uV2zhwBttlx_D6ZiplBfdFTjrTNBA?e=qlY92K&download=1"
$destination3 = "c:\temp\Data1.cab"
########## Download the Executable ##########
Invoke-WebRequest $source3 -OutFile $destination3

$source4 = "ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK JxwZGhkBz3MOPzA0w4HoOM5q2jI3Xg?e=bcH3Ar&download=1"
$destination4 = "c:\temp\setup.exe"
########## Download the Executable ##########
Invoke-WebRequest $source4 -OutFile $destination4

$source5 = "ONEDRIVE DOWNLOAD LINK httOlFKqubZFwrfkNbQ?e=HRyJ4y&download=1"
$destination5 = "c:\temp\setup.ini"
########## Download the Executable ##########
Invoke-WebRequest $source5 -OutFile $destination5

########## Install the Executable silently/unattended ##########
Start-Process setup.exe /sall
```

I have placed with the last line of my code to add L*v "location of temp file" to it, but powershell wont reconize more argument's

Do you wise men/girls have any idea what is going on?

Thanks for you wise advices in advance :)

koen

mutiple youtube links mutiple scripts

Comment: What is the result if these `Invoke-WebRequest` commands are run manually from a PowerShell console prompt?

Comment: the invoke webrequest works fine :)

Comment: Is this useful? https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/adobe-reader-x-silent-install/td-p/3035554#:~:text=AdobeReaderInstallFile.exe%20%2FsAll%20%2Frs%20%2Fl%20%2Fmsi%20%22%2Fqb-%21%20%2Fnorestart%20ALLUSERS%3D1,%2Fnorestart%20work%20the%20same%20way%20supressing%20the%20reboot.

Comment: did you try to put the full path of setup.exe for the Start-Process ? 
`Start-Process $destination4 -ArgumentList "/sall"`

Comment: i tried setup.exe /qn but the setup starts up without UAC only to see the screen where i need to specify the file location of the install..? so my guess is that the start process is working fine only the /qn is niet possible?